# Passwordless login keyring not being unlocked upon login

Tags: 18.04, login, ubuntu-mate, keyrings, seahorse

In Ubuntu Mate 18.04 32 bit, when I inspect my Login keyring in Users and Groups ("`seahorse`") and hover over it it displays the description "**A keyring that is automatically unlocked on login**" in the tooltip. That is clear enough. If I create a new keyring it does not get that same tooltip, implying that this behavior is unique to the Login keyring.

- I have set an **empty password** on the Login keyring as detailed in several other answers in order to make it unlockable without a password, thereby preventing keyring password prompts upon **autologin** (which would otherwise defeat the purpose of not having to enter a password). At the same time I emptied the Login keyring of its contents.
- I have also created a new default keyring to store my passwords in. I did this with the assumption that my new keyring will only prompt me for a password when it's actually being used by a client application, unlike the Login keyring which per its description will attempt to unlock upon login regardless of need.

Here's what I don't understand:

1. After logging in the Login keyring is not unlocked, according to `seahorse`, which contradicts its own description.
2. Trying to unlock the Login keyring manually in `seahorse` does not work -- it just remains locked. Other times it works to manually unlock it...once. After that it can be locked but not unlocked again. Confusing, and doesn't help me understand what's going on.
3. On logging in I'm now prompted to unlock my newly created default keyring. The dialog is not telling me what specific application is requesting access to the keyring. In the absence of any concrete information about which app needs access I'm assuming that it's asking just because I logged in, which seems to defeat the purpose of having the Login keyring suggest that this behavior is unique to it.
4. If I remove the password from my new default keyring, it now gets unlocked upon login while the Login keyring does not. I was expecting the opposite to happen.
5. I don't see how I can differentiate between the sources of keyring unlock prompts, and hence how to actually understand what's going on. How do I tell whether the prompt is because of me logging in as opposed to a specific request from a specific app?

Could you explain these points to me please?

I don't mind unlocking a keyring when I actually want to use its contents -- just not at login -- but this point I don't even know whether I'm being asked because I logged in or because some random application immediately starts trying to anticipate needs I don't have.

Comment: Can you clearly ask a question.

Comment: @David Sure. It's done.